how to install kubeadm-1.29.11
When I tried to install kubeadm in centos like this:
yum install -y kubeadm-1.29.11-150500.1.1

shows error:
Last metadata expiration check: 0:40:43 ago on Sun 24 Nov 2024 04:15:12 PM CST.
All matches were filtered out by exclude filtering for argument: kubeadm-1.29.11-150500.1.1
Error: Unable to find a match: kubeadm-1.29.11-150500.1.1

what should I do to install this version of kubeadm? This is the available info:
[root@iZm5e2jhfbrshckqh6qdbuZ ~]# sudo yum list --showduplicates kubeadm --disableexcludes=kubernetes
Last metadata expiration check: 0:36:48 ago on Sun 24 Nov 2024 04:15:12 PM CST.
Installed Packages
kubeadm.x86_64                                                                    1.29.6-150500.1.1                                                                    @kubernetes
Available Packages
kubeadm.aarch64                                                                   1.29.0-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.ppc64le                                                                   1.29.0-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.s390x                                                                     1.29.0-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.src                                                                       1.29.0-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.x86_64                                                                    1.29.0-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.aarch64                                                                   1.29.1-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.ppc64le                                                                   1.29.1-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.s390x                                                                     1.29.1-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.src                                                                       1.29.1-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.x86_64                                                                    1.29.1-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.aarch64                                                                   1.29.2-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.ppc64le                                                                   1.29.2-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.s390x                                                                     1.29.2-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.src                                                                       1.29.2-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.x86_64                                                                    1.29.2-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.aarch64                                                                   1.29.3-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.ppc64le                                                                   1.29.3-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.s390x                                                                     1.29.3-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.src                                                                       1.29.3-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.x86_64                                                                    1.29.3-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.aarch64                                                                   1.29.4-150500.2.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.ppc64le                                                                   1.29.4-150500.2.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.s390x                                                                     1.29.4-150500.2.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.src                                                                       1.29.4-150500.2.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.x86_64                                                                    1.29.4-150500.2.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.aarch64                                                                   1.29.5-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.ppc64le                                                                   1.29.5-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.s390x                                                                     1.29.5-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.src                                                                       1.29.5-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.x86_64                                                                    1.29.5-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.aarch64                                                                   1.29.6-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.ppc64le                                                                   1.29.6-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.s390x                                                                     1.29.6-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.src                                                                       1.29.6-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.x86_64                                                                    1.29.6-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.aarch64                                                                   1.29.7-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.ppc64le                                                                   1.29.7-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.s390x                                                                     1.29.7-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.src                                                                       1.29.7-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.x86_64                                                                    1.29.7-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.aarch64                                                                   1.29.8-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.ppc64le                                                                   1.29.8-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.s390x                                                                     1.29.8-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.src                                                                       1.29.8-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.x86_64                                                                    1.29.8-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.aarch64                                                                   1.29.9-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.ppc64le                                                                   1.29.9-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.s390x                                                                     1.29.9-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.src                                                                       1.29.9-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.x86_64                                                                    1.29.9-150500.1.1                                                                    kubernetes
kubeadm.aarch64                                                                   1.29.10-150500.1.1                                                                   kubernetes
kubeadm.ppc64le                                                                   1.29.10-150500.1.1                                                                   kubernetes
kubeadm.s390x                                                                     1.29.10-150500.1.1                                                                   kubernetes
kubeadm.src                                                                       1.29.10-150500.1.1                                                                   kubernetes
kubeadm.x86_64                                                                    1.29.10-150500.1.1                                                                   kubernetes
kubeadm.aarch64                                                                   1.29.11-150500.1.1                                                                   kubernetes
kubeadm.ppc64le                                                                   1.29.11-150500.1.1                                                                   kubernetes
kubeadm.s390x                                                                     1.29.11-150500.1.1                                                                   kubernetes
kubeadm.src                                                                       1.29.11-150500.1.1                                                                   kubernetes
kubeadm.x86_64                                                                    1.29.11-150500.1.1                                                                   kubernetes


Have you try to install just kubeadm.x86_64?
